# Unix Shell Script Issue

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

Referring to following Unix Shell Script, when I type in the correct command to run the <(./TCPHost.out $2), I am receiving the following error:

```
open[1905:26153] Metadata.framework [Error]: void _MDItemMarkAsUsedForPath(CFStringRef): was called with a NULL path
```

This is the only one I'm receiving this error on. Can someone explain to me why this is happened? The weird thing is that it's technically working, but it doesn't open another shell like the others do.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "Server" ]
then
    echo *********** SERVER IS RUNNING ***********
    open -a Terminal ./TCPServer.out
fi

if [ "$1" = "Host" ]
then
    echo HOST IS RUNNING
    open -a Terminal <(./TCPHost.out $2)
fi

if [ "$1" = "Client" ]
then
    open -a Terminal ./TCPClient.out
fi
```

Comment: The bash script should be called with at least 2 parameters.  Only the second one is passed as ``$2``.  If not, it is possible that this is causing the error.  "TCPHost.out" isn't a standard unix command so people on Stackoverflow have no idea how it might behave - and this is essentially your question

Comment: how are you executing the script? What parameters are you passing to it?

Comment: @vmachan the .out files are compiled version of my C code. It works perfectly fine when I run Server and Client, but not host. My parameters are for example ./Launch.sh Server

Comment: or ./Launch.sh Host 5001

Comment: And they are all in the same directory, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @Vorsprung Please see my comments above.

Comment: I know these .out files run perfectly fine because when I do ./TCPHost 5001 it works as it should. @vmachan

Comment: run your script as ``bash -vx`` to see more output of what it is doing

Comment: go on there: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-conditional-expression/ and try to see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
open -a Terminal "./TCPHost.out $2"
```